# Losing focus for interrupts

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have some code that catches keydown and looks for Alt-D:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
     if((e.keyCode == 68) && e.altKey){     // Alt-D
    e.preventDefault();

         - code to duplicate an element  - 

      }
});
```

This works fine the first time, but after going though my "code to duplicate an element" the next Alt-D is not caught.  In fact, no interrupts are caught, until I click back in the body.  It appears that the  "code to duplicate an element" does something that directs interrupts to some other window.

Could someone suggest what I must be doing in my duplicate code for this to happen? I've tried applying focus() to the element that was created by the duplicate code but that doesn't get my interrupts to be seen.  I have to click in the window to get them back.  (The duplicate code is way to messy to include here.)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Alt D focuses the address bar, is that default action still happening?

Comment: No.  If I type, the characters don't go into the address bar.  I don't see them appearing anywhere.

Comment: Interrupts ALWAYS make me lose focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.preventdefault()
return false;

both are required i do believe for cross browser compatibility.

are you creating the element. and trying to set focus before the element is actually created?

alt key itself. takes focus out of the document, and to the tool bar. 
try creating an array  or global variables, for keydown, for both alt and D key.

so 2 actual "keydown" events happen. each event you can use event.preventdefault(); return false; so alt is being prevented. and D key is being prevented.

at moment guessing only D key is being prevented. and not the "alt key"  ((holding D key down first then pressing ALT.  vs ALT being press down first then D key))

Comment: Yes, the Alt key by itself turns on a File/View/Edit menu at the top of Firefox. The thing that was stealing the focus turned out to be a Firebug debugger interrupt. Clearing those keeps the focus in my window and I don't have to click there again to see et new events.  Thanks your input.  It helped.